# Store Images Offline in coded form in HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

Suppose I have Webpage that has some images, I don't want to store images physically in a folder or as a link in Html but I want to store that images in HTML such that whenever I open that page (Offline), images gets displayed.
Any Technology can be used.
I don't want to use any database too.

Comment: convert your image into blob data and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Images can be encoded in base64 format and loaded as data uri. Such a data uri follows this syntax: `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`. So an example for such an embedded image could be:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABADX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGu...">
```

However this rarely makes sense, except for tiny images like icons. In most cases the better approach is to use another format, one that is suited for offline usage. `DeJaVu`, `ePub` or `PDF` maybe.

If the page is created *strictly only* for offline usage, then you could also use a file archive like `tar` or `zip`. That way you can pack a folder including images into a single file. Modern desktop environments allow to open such an archive in a transparent manner. So when you open it and chose the index document in there images contained in the same archive and referenced in a relative manner will be displayed. but keep in mind that this depends on the desktop environment. In slim or less advanced environments yo might have to unpack the archive first which is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/storage/sdcard0/Android/my-web/pictures/test.jpg />
```

I using that code for test offline in my phone only transfer as a media from my laptop to my phone.

1. Changes the "my-web" be the name of folder you give in folder you place it
2. in your "my-web" folder,  Create a new folder named "pictures" and move all img format.
3. delete the "Android" if doesnot work and try it again
4. if you transfer the file to internal memory just use "sdcard0" if you move it in external or sdcard changes the name be what the sd or external names